# What is the use of capacity check IF condition in ArrayList source code

Tags: java, arraylist

Below is the the source code of `ArrayList`'s `ensureCapacity` and `add` method:

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    ensureCapacity(size + 1); // Increments modCount!!
    elementData[size++] = e;
    return true;
}

public void ensureCapacity(int minCapacity) {
    modCount++;
    int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
    if (minCapacity > oldCapacity) {
        Object oldData[] = elementData;
        int newCapacity = (oldCapacity * 3) / 2 + 1;
        if (newCapacity < minCapacity)
            newCapacity = minCapacity;
        // minCapacity is usually close to size, so this is a win:
        elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
    }
}
```

Now, with this code, we are almost doubling the capacity, when we this `ensureCapacity` method is called then it is called as `ensureCapacity(size + 1);`.

So, considering total capacity of AL is 10, and the given iteration current size is 10, so ensure capacity will be called as `ensureCapacity(11)`, when this method will get executed then `newCapacity` will become 16 and `minCapacity` will be 11, so `if (newCapacity < minCapacity)` will return FALSE, and this will always be the case whenever capacity of AL is increased.

Now, if `if (newCapacity < minCapacity)` always return FALSE then what is the use this this IF condition. I know JDK source code is heavily peer reviewed so chances are high that I am missing something, please help me identify the purpose of this IF condition.

Answer (score 2):

You had missed the scenarios when `ensureCapacity` method will be called from `addAll` method of `ArrayList` like `public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {`, and called like `ensureCapacity(size + numNew);`, here `numNew` could be very high count which makes is possible that `if (newCapacity < minCapacity)` will return TRUE.

Comment: I would also guess that ArrayList isn't shrunk when items are removed

Comment: @LanceToth ArrayList doesn't shrink, when item is removed from array list then that particular index will start pointing to `NULL`.

Comment: Of course, all subsequent items will be moved to fix that, but the "memory allocation" will not change?

Comment: I am not sure what you do mean by "memory allocation will not change". When array list is dynamically resized then more memory is allocated for the array list using `Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);`